# Representing Table Data From An Excel Sheet

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I'm currently in the process of automating some of my workplace  QA tasks using Selenium webdriver with C#.

My next task is to be able to read from an excel sheet, navigate to a matrix of checkboxes and check the relevant ones based on the table.

The table looks as follows.

```
Task    Module 1    Module 2    Module 3    Module 4 
T1      True        False       True        False 
T2      False       False       False       True
```

So there is a task (T1, T2 so on) and modules. A Task can be made up of multiple modules.

So for task one the user will need to complete modules 1 and 2.

I've successfully pulled the data from the excel sheet and I'm now just looking at how to store this.

I'm not really sure where to even start with this so any help would be appreciated.

(also apologies for badly laid out table.)

Comment: Thanks @totalfreakingnoob for editing the table.

Answer (score 0):

Take the Excel table one row at a time. Read row 1 (for T1) and store the values for Module 1-4 in booleans. Then use the booleans to direct the code flow on whether to execute Module X or not.

NOTE: `readValueFromExcel()` would be replaced with your function that is used to pull data from Excel.

```
bool module1 = readValueFromExcel("Module 1");
bool module2 = readValueFromExcel("Module 2");
bool module3 = readValueFromExcel("Module 3");
bool module4 = readValueFromExcel("Module 4");

if (module1)
{
    // execute Module 1 tests
}
if (module2)
{
    // execute Module 2 tests
}

// ... and so on
```